# How to show online presence using Facebook login OAuth?

Tags: facebook, windows-phone-7, facebook-chat

I'm trying to develop a Facebook chat application for Windows Phone 7.

I have used `..../outh/authorize` to login. I get the API for the login and have successfully logged in to my account using the access_token I got from ...../outh/access_token and the FQL query I got with my online friends. But the problem is my friends don't see me online.

I've used `user_online_presence`, `friends_online_presence`, `xmpp_login`, `user_checkins`, `friends_checkins`, `publish_checkins` as permissions.

How can I show my online presence in the application?

Answer (score 2):

Your friends won't see you online unless you're logged into Facebook's chat service (Though you should be able to see them online with the appropriate permission)

The API for using Facebook chat in your application is documented here: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/chat/

Using this once you are logged in via the Chat API you should appear as online to your friends (when other people query your online status via the API). Those documents are for implementing your own login to Facebook chat, and specifically they focus on the ways in which Facebook chat differs from standard XMPP implementations.

It's less straightforward than implementing many of the other APIs but there is some sample code in Python here: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/chat/#code - there may be a C# or other .NET example around but I haven't seen it.